# Viewing result query in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, clip

I have some queries which clip rasters from polygon.

So how I can see my result query in postgis or How I can check my query true or false ?

Comment: You can use ST_AsPNG. See the section on PLPython in [this article](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/using_raster.xml.html#RT_Ras) for one way to actually generate an image from the output of ST_AsPNG which produces a byte stream representing a png.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using QGIS to view the results of your queries.

To check if your query is true, you could run [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) to make sure the polygons and rasters actually intersect.

Comment: st_intersects() are true, so I expect that my query about clip raster are fine, but when using Qgis to view my query result, there is a big black square

I used st_transform() on my query, so must I use st_transform() in my result ???

Comment: This seems like a separate question. You might want to edit your initial question to be more detailed, including screenshots and steps you have taken.

Answer (score 0):

st_intersects() are true, so I expect that my query about clip raster are fine, but when using Qgis to view my query result, there is a big black square

I used st_transform() on my query, so must I use st_transform() in my result ???